# aws sam cli-colored output in jenkins console

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, ansi-colors

From version `0.33.1` onwards, [aws-sam-cli](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases) supports colored output. I'm trying to run the `sam deploy` command from Jenkins pipeline and the output is not displaying in colored format. I've installed [ANSIColor Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/) and wrapped the sam deploy command with `ansiColor('xterm') {}`. The command works as expected and the Cloudformation stack is getting created. The concern is the output is not in colored format.

```
node {
stage('Example') {
    ansiColor('xterm') {
        sh "sam deploy --parameter-overrides ${someparameter} --template-file ${templatefile} --stack-name ${stackname} --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM  --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --no-execute-changeset"
   }
 }
}
```

In order to verify my Jenkins, I tried test-snippet in Jenkins and it displayed the colored output.

```
ansiColor('xterm') {
    stage "\u001B[31mI'm Red\u001B[0m Now not"
}
```

[image]

So Jenkins is able to display ANSI color, but the `aws-sam-cli` output is not in colored format.

Any ideas or pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`aws-sam-cli` uses [`click`](https://github.com/pallets/click) library to format its output, including color handling.

The [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/utils/#ansi-colors) for `click` explains why you're seeing what you're seeing:

> Starting with Click 2.0, the echo() function gained extra
>   functionality to deal with ANSI colors and styles. [...]
>
> Primarily this means that:
>
> - Click’s echo() function will automatically strip ANSI color codes if the stream is not connected to a terminal.

This is a typical behavior of most programs, however some programs allow overriding this, usually with `--color` parameter.

In your case, I'd suggest asking for an enhancement on `click`'s [issue tracker](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues).

Edit: There's [already been one](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1090).